# how to draw this timeline with jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

any ideas to build such timeline[image] with compose

Comment: ListItem and PathEffect.

Answer (score 1):

i don't really see what are you facing difficulty with but if you are looking to draw the line behind the list of item you can make use of drawBehind Modifier also keep in mind you need to make use of BoxWithConstraints to get the width and the height of the screen to draw the line precisely and adapt it for your need, here is an example :

```
  LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(color = Color.Gray)
            .drawBehind {
                 {
                    drawLine(//implement you own logic to draw the line in from which offset(x,y))
                }
            }
    )
```